# cvsps fails to parse through the git cvsimport

Tags: git

I'm using git cvsimport. I'm issuing the following command

```
git cvsimport -v -p -x -o master -C folder -d :pserver:user:paswword@host:/path/to/cvs/repo path/to/cvs/module
```

I can see that all the cvs tree structure is traveled but in the end, I guess when cvsps is preparing to parse the patchset(s) file(s) the following error is thrown

```
"Error: Log file parsing error. (3)"
```

The installed cvsps version (through cygwin) is 2.2b1-1.